# How to manually install ICS on Sony Ericsson Phones?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, 2.3-gingerbread, updates, sony-xperia-mini-pro

Attempting update from 2.3.4 to 4.x and the pc companion software keeps telling me my phone is up to date! Anyone know if it's possible to do a manual install?

Comment: what year is your handset?

Comment: 2011. Last September - it's SI is one of those listed as eligible for an update. I'm guessing it's something to do with my network T-Mobile in the UK?

Comment: FYI - I was constantly refreshing the sonymobile's page to see if my 2011 ST15i's SI number showed up. But no, it did not, it was when I checked Sony's PC Companion suite for an update itself, then after the software got updated, it recognized that the ST15i was eligible for upgrade to ICS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually install update using Flashtool,and also you need ftf file for it,

http://androxyde.github.com/index.html?1349610344000 -Flash tool

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1918920 -ftf file.

Comment: That will not work unless the boot loader is unlocked!

Comment: You do not need unlocked bootloader for it.